# Is it possible to use functions from c++ namespaces with luajit ffi?

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

I've got a lot of c++ code which contains a lot of functions and classes in namespaces (boost, for example).
Now I'm trying to embed LuaJiT2 as script engine, but I cannot find anything about calling functions and using other stuff from namespaces.
So, Is it possible to pass the functions from c++ namespaces to LuaJIT with the FFI?

Comment: I'd assume you'd need to export them with C style decoration via extern "C", but i doubt you'll be able to get anything like class methods/templates or non-exported namespaced functions

Comment: Exposing boost to Lua is probably not a fantastic idea either. You're better off exposing a limited functional API based on your actual use-case.

Comment: Thanks, @jsimmons, but boost was an example and "a limited functional API based on your actual use-case" is much bigger than boost library functional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the standard Lua API to expose namespace-scope functions, as well as class static functions, to Lua. This is done exactly as you would with the regular Lua interpreter, since LuaJIT is drop-in compatible with it.

But you can't use FFI, because FFI is based on a C-based parsing of the header files. And you're using C++ syntax. FFI is not the *only* way to use LuaJIT; it's just one that is based on C.

Any of the C++-specific binding APIs that use Lua (Luabind, SWIG, etc) should work just fine with LuaJIT as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use different name mangling other than C. The reason why its not "common" is because the C++ name mangling is very compiler/platform specific:
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00502.html

So this sort of declaration is valid:

```
ffi.cdef[[
void Test1_Method1(void) asm("_ZN5Test17Method1Ev");
]]
```

And you can then call Test1_Method1.
Mike Pall has done an amazing job with luajit. So many great features.